# How to use Adobe Reader Mobile SDK 9 to develop pdf/epub reader?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

How can I use Adobe Reader Mobile SDK 9 to develop a pdf/epub reader for blackberry device?

Please help me if you have any idea about Adobe Reader mobile SDK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, RMSDK can't be used on Java platforms unless you can use JNI.

Comment: Just to clarify: RMSDK is a C++ library therefore, you will need to build it using Android NDK, and then write a JNI layer so your Java app can talk to it.

Comment: Right, and as far as my knowledge - Blackberry doesnt have JNI support.

Answer (score 0):

I've been building apps for Android and iOS with RMSDK. What exactly is the problem? Android uses NDK for accessing some native code, necessary to run the DRM and view workflows. iOS has everything sorted out within XCode, including the C/C++ dependencies.

Comment: the problem seems to be the BlackBerry :)

Comment: I was asking about Blackberry platform, not the android. I am well aware about android NDK, I was just looking if Blackberry have something like that or not.

Comment: have you completed the development of apps using RmSdk in android and ios @hcabral. can you please tell me where is the starting point to develop the app in android using rmsdk. Please

Comment: @user1806231 you can start by contacting one of Adobe vendors and filing paperwork to use the trial version of RMSDK, which is in fact fully functional. The SDK has documents that will help you build and customize your apps.

Comment: thanks.. can we use their white label apps..@hcabral

Comment: Yes, they allow you to use and modify their own apps (iOS, Android, Windows).