# Develop ePub file reader in iOS 5

Tags: ios5, render, epub

I want to develop ePub & PDF reader for iOS devices. 
For PDF reader , I can display PDF in Web View. So I don't have any problem with PDF.

For ePub files, my idea is 
1) Download epub files from server & extract it to Documents directory as per requirement.
2) Parse extracted files & display it.
3) Once app closed , delete extracted files from Socuments directory.

Required functionality :-

1) Increase / Decrease Font size & brightness

2) Bookmark

3) Left & Right Swipe gesture OR Curl effect like changing pages from book

4) Orientation suuport

5) Display contents from Book (List)

6) SEARCH Functionality

7) Optionally display Page number

My questions are :-

1) Does any one know a good iOS library for ePub reader other than [AePubReader](https://github.com/springRan/AePubReader)?

2) I saw this link for for [RMSDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824990/how-to-use-adobe-reader-mobile-sdk-9-to-develop-pdf-epub-reader). Anybody know about this ? Does it support iOS ?

3) Where should I display extracted contents in order to manipulate the font size & brightness ? In WebView or TextView ?

Any knid of help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This answer might get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format

Comment: @iOSAppDev Do you find any Library Project for the above que. I'm need the same functionality in one of my project.

Comment: @SumitSharma Sorry... I didn't get any library.

Comment: @iOSAppDev Hi have you got any solution please let me help ASAP on badri.vk@gmail.com i have the same requirements.

Comment: @Arpit I didn't get any library / solution for this. Sorry can't help you

Answer (score 1):

Use UITextView to load text by parsing each html/xhtml file. Use page view controller to get page navigation style