# Parse epub information, like title, author

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser, epub

I like to make a eBook app for iOS, something like iBooks, but with some special features. My questions is regarding the epub files. I can unzip them with ZipArchivos and storing each epub in its own folder.

So far so good. The epub's are imported to my app, either by email attachment, Safari or with iTunes Sync. Also this is working well.

When getting a new epub I want to extract several information from it, like title, author, publisher ... and to store this information in CoreData.

Is this possible and if yes, does anyone have a solution for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933874/develop-epub-file-reader-in-ios-5

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the two discussions liked above.

You might also want to check Readium SDK out (if its licensing terms fit into your project): https://github.com/readium/readium-sdk

There are also "premade EPUB-support SDKs" which you can buy online, but in my experience they are quite poor.

For our own hybrid app Menestrello ( https://readbeyond.it/menestrello/ ), the native iOS part does smart unzipping (via the Objective-Zip library) + basic metadata parsing (title, author, etc.) just to populate the library view. The "real" parsing required when the EPUB is opened in reading view is done in JS. I wrote both parsers (native iOS and JS) from scratch.